# Scala type mismatch using multiple generic

Tags: scala, generics, constructor

I'm trying to use Scala to prototype the functionality of lazy endless list for my lambda calculus classes. The public constructor takes two arguments and should create LazyList[A,A].

```
class LazyList[A,B] private (private val first: A, private val mapper: A => B, private val successor: A => A) {
  def this(first: A, successor: A => A) = this(first, (e: A) => e, successor)

  def head: B = mapper(first)

  def tail(): LazyList[A,B] = new LazyList(successor(first), mapper, successor)
  def map[R](func: B => R) = new LazyList[A, R](first, func.compose(mapper), successor)
  def at(index: Long): B = if (index == 0L) head else tail().at(index - 1)
  def sublist(end: Long): List[B] = if (end == 0L) List(head) else head :: tail().sublist(end - 1)

  override def toString = s"LazyList($first, $mapper, $successor)"
}
```

But the code compilation fails with error.

```
Error:(20, 65) type mismatch;
 found   : e.type (with underlying type A)
 required: B
  def this(first: A, successor: A => A) = this(first, (e: A) => e, successor)
                                                            ^
```

What actually am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameterized signatures inside the class don't have any info about the relation of type `B` to type `A`, and thus the compiler generally thinks that everywhere inside the `LazyList`'s body `B` is not `A`, that's why it compiler complains when you try to assign `A => A` to `A => B`.

You should create an alternative constructor not as `this()`, but as a factory method in companion object. Note the `A` of this usage is a parameter which is not in any way related to the `A` inside LazyList's body:

```
object LazyList {
  def apply[A](first: A, successor: A => A): LazyList[A, A] = new LazyList(first, identity, successor) 
}
```